# Find first element in list of pairs of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to figure out how to write the function lookup(List) such that it searches for the first element of a tuple in list of two element tuples.
I get the error: 
Name undefined when I want assign the description a variable under lookup(List).

```
def TupletoList():
    List = []
    menufun(List)

def menufun(List):
    print("""
    Alternatives
    -----------
    1. Insert
    2. Search
    3: Exit
    """)
    val = int(input("Choose an alternative by inputting its assigned number."))
    if val == 1:
        inputfun(List)
    elif val == 2:
        lookup(List)
    elif val == 3:
        funcex(List)


def inputfun(List):
    b = input("Word")
    for b in List:
        if True:
            print("The word is already in the list")
            menufun(List)

    else:
        c = input("Description")
        a = (b, c)
        List.append(a)
        print(List)
        lookup(List)


def lookup(List):
        d = input("Write the word you want to look up")
        for d in List:
            if True:
                print(d, "means", #description)

def funcex(List):
    exit()
```

Comment: Is there really a `#` on this line: `print(d, "means", #description)`, if so that would comment out the rest of the line so probably needs to be removed.

Comment: You might not need to pass `List` in your every function call. That is an overkill. Also I'd prefer `dict` as the proper DS here

Comment: A variable that assign the corresponding description. However I did not assign anything as dont know what I should assign if its for any (general case) description.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, your list will contain a tuple of `(word, description)` and you want your lookup function to prompt for a word and then print `"<word> means <description>"`. If that's the case, I'd recommend changing your lookup function to something like:

```py
def lookup(List):
    word = input("Write the word you want to look up")
    for (w, d) in List:
        if w == word:
            print(w, "means", d)
```

This will loop through every entry in your list and check if the first value in the entry, `w`, is equal to the desired word.

#### A few other recommendations

- I would recommend not using `List` as a variable name as that is already defined by python. Something like `word_list` seems more appropriate.
- A list is probably not the optimal data structure for this task. You could use a dictionary where the word is the key and the value is a description. Something like `{ 'apple': 'this is a fruit', 'celery': 'this is a vegetable' }`.

  - This would allow you to simply check if the word is in the dictionary rather than having to search every time (e.g. `if word in word_dict: print(word, word_dict[word])`)
  - I can add an example of this if you would like
- I'm not sure this pattern is doing what you expect it to be doing

```py
# Take input and assign it to b
b = input("Word")

# For every element in list, assign it to b and run the body.
for b in List:
    # We've now lost our reference to our input word because we've reassigned b to the current element in the list.

    # I'm assuming you want to check if our element is equal to the input word. 
    # This won't do that. This always evaluates to True meaning it will always print.
    # You need to have some condition like input_word == b.
    # My example lookup function shows a pretty similar situation.
    if True: 
        print("The word is already in the list")

        # Wouldn't necessarily recommend doing this. 
        # Using an explicit loop at the menu_fun would probably better.
        menufun(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your to the following:

```
def lookup(List):
    d = input("Write the word you want to look up")
    for x in List:
        if x == d:
            print(d, "means",  "Some description")
```